# Tomact7 is running with multiple process ids while having only one instance in ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: java, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, ubuntu-server

I am running tomcat7 is ubuntu 14.04 on digital ocean server and i am having only one instance of tomcat7 but when using top command it is showing 4 process with name tomcat7 and my the process are taxing more cpu and my tomcat7 is always stopping.i want to know how to stop that process and how to know the source of it and by using    ps xaf the source is showing as ./sshd -c ugnlebxtuw.conf -t 1   [image]

Comment: This is showing 4 processes with user=tomcat7, not 4 processes called tomcat7.

Comment: how to restrict that user and normally run tomcat7 @jr593